Changed 46.04$ to only 0.85$ in solana, but the coin didn't dip, can someone help?
I lost my 46.04$ from unkown transaction, i just swapped around 46.04$, 101.06047 Buio, Mascot of the Unholy Year coin, to Solana, after that, somehow I have 0.85$ on my wallet, and got only 0.00008 Solana, how is that possible? I swapped 46.04$ and got only 0.85$ back, I think it is something from the application, please help me because the Buio coin price is now 0.92$, so how did I get only 0.85$ back in Solana?
this is the coin I swapped: 2SXriLXBgu1atu7fRKG2QW2MV3NYLTGLo9iCz94epump
please someone help me get my  money back, I would really appreciate it...
Kind Regards.

Either the price is not reflected properly in the Phantom Wallet, or they are playing around with the wallet fee, right? There's no way to get it. The customer service center doesn't work.

Same thing just happend to me got 100$ cad and put 5$ into a coin come back 20 minutes later and I got 1.60$ like wth is this (have ss proof btw)
